# YOLO custom object detector single epoch training for 3 days

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dataset, yolo, imageai

I am trying to implement YOLO object custom object detector. I have downloaded 1000 images for train data and 100 images for validation data seperately in colab. The code is running perfectly, except collab notebook takes almost one day to get single epoch.Below is the sample code. Also how can i use custom Human hand dataset of google open image like kaggle without downloading it on collab.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Hnad_detector.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1083eIr_O3Dge1pnMgqliZz9zzMqRtaZC
"""

!git clone https://github.com/EscVM/OIDv4_ToolKit.git

!pip install awscli
!pip install urllib3

!pip3 install -r '/content/OIDv4_ToolKit/requirements.txt'

!python '/content/OIDv4_ToolKit/main.py' downloader --classes '/content/OIDv4_ToolKit/classes.txt' --type_csv train --limit 1000

import os
dir = '/content/OID/Dataset/train/'
for folder in os.listdir(dir):
  print('Number for files in '+folder+'=',len(os.listdir(dir+folder)))

import os
dir = '/content/OID/Dataset/train/'

for folder in os.listdir(dir):
  for file in os.listdir(dir+folder+'/Label')[:5]:
    print(dir+folder+'/Label'+'/'+file)

!git clone https://github.com/thehetpandya/OIDv4_annotation_tool.git

!pip install -r OIDv4_annotation_tool/requirements.txt

from subprocess import check_output
source = '/content/OID/Dataset/train'

for folder in os.listdir(source):
  target = f'{source}/{folder}'
  output = check_output(["python", '/content/OIDv4_annotation_tool/OIDv4_to_VOC.py', "--sourcepath" , f"{source}/{folder}", "--dest_path", f"{target}"])

import shutil
for folder in os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train'):
  print(folder,len(os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train/'+folder)))

for folder in os.listdir(dir):
  shutil.rmtree(f'/{dir}/{folder}/Label')

#import shutil
#shutil.rmtree('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Apple')
#shutil.rmtree('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Light switch')
#shutil.rmtree('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Orange')

import os 
print(len(os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand')))

!pip install annotated-images

!pip install annotated-images



import os
images = []
xml = []
for file in os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/'):
  if file.endswith(".jpg"):
    imagepath = '/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/{}'.format(file)

    shutil.move(imagepath,'/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/images')
  if file.endswith(".xml"):
   
    imagepath = '/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/{}'.format(file)
    shutil.move(imagepath,'/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/annotations')

for images in os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/images'):
  print(images[0:17])

shutil.move('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/images','/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/train')
shutil.move('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/annotations','/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/train')

!python '/content/OIDv4_ToolKit/main.py' downloader --classes '/content/OIDv4_ToolKit/classes.txt' --type_csv train --limit 300

from subprocess import check_output
source = '/content/OID/Dataset/train'

for folder in os.listdir(source):
  target = f'{source}/{folder}'
  output = check_output(["python", '/content/OIDv4_annotation_tool/OIDv4_to_VOC.py', "--sourcepath" , f"{source}/{folder}", "--dest_path", f"{target}"])

import shutil
for folder in os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train'):
  print(folder,len(os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train/'+folder)))

for folder in os.listdir(dir):
  shutil.rmtree(f'/{dir}/{folder}/Label')

import os
images = []
xml = []
for file in os.listdir('/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/'):
  if file.endswith(".jpg"):
    imagepath = '/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/{}'.format(file)

    shutil.move(imagepath,'/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/validation/images')
  if file.endswith(".xml"):
   
    imagepath = '/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/{}'.format(file)
    shutil.move(imagepath,'/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/validation/annotations')

!wget 'https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/essential-v4/pretrained-yolov3.h5'

#!pip install keras==2.2.4
#!pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
!pip install imageai==2.1.5
#!wget 'https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/1.0/resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5'

import tensorflow as tf

import imageai as imageai

from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer

trainer = DetectionModelTrainer()
trainer.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
trainer.setDataDirectory(data_directory="/content/OID/Dataset/train/Human hand/")
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["Human hand"], batch_size=8, num_experiments=100, train_from_pretrained_model="/content/pretrained-yolov3.h5")
trainer.trainModel()
```

Comment: Your colab setting are correct? Are you using a GPU to train your model?

Comment: I am using GPU in hardware acceleration, but COLAB keeps giving signs that YOU ARE NOT USING GPU.